# Why can't RefCell be used as a self parameter

Tags: rust

You can do this:

```rust
impl Foo {
  fn foo(self: &Rc<Self>) {}
}
```

But not this:

```rust
impl Foo {
  fn foo(self: &Rc<RefCell<Self>>) {}
}
```

The former is quite useful - e.g. I can have methods return objects containing weak references to `self`. But because I can't use `RefCell` I can't return anything that would mutate `self`.

There are ways around this (e.g. wrapping the whole struct in `RefCell` internally) but none as convenient for my current task as just allowing `self: &Rc<RefCell<>>`.

The grammar allowed is described [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/associated-items.html#methods). It allows `Box`, `Rc`, `Arc` and `Pin` but not `RefCell`. Why?

Comment: Are you asking "why haven't it done" in which case this should be closed as opinion-based, or "how does rustc knows it's disallowed" or something like that in which case you should clarify?

Comment: This is an [unstable feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44874) which works on nightly. It appears that there's not much work being done on it right now, though.

Comment: @isaactfa [It still does not allow `RefCell`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3d74da8900666b4e438492527828013). As far as I remember it tracks only raw pointers as self types and defining your own.

Comment: I don't think there is an official answer I can cite. The best I can come with is that `RefCell` is not a pointer type and thus it is not appropriate for `self`. Thus I want to close that (and I can't close a question alone, only if others will agree).

Comment: I don't believe `Pin` is a pointer type either though is it?

Comment: `Pin` is considered a smart pointer (it even impls `Deref[Mut]`).

Comment: Also note that when `Pin` does not implement `Deref`, it's exactly because it's supposed to be an "opaque" pointer.

Comment: Ok so it sounds like the (NOT OPINION BASED!) answer is "because `self` is intended to be for pointers or smart pointers - types that have `Deref` implementations - and `RefCell` doesn't because it requires explicit `.borrow()` calls". Thanks for the info.

Comment: I explicitly said this is my opinion, and I have no official source to backup this claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the time of this writing, in August 2022, method receiver type support is still fairly limited to a handful of types, and compositions of those types. You've noticed that `RefCell` is not among them.

`arbitrary_self_types`, a feature for expanding the possible types of `self`, has a [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44874) for discussing its implementation. From the discussion, it seems that this feature is currently targeting types that implement `Deref[Mut]`, which `RefCell` does not implement. [A few comments](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44874#issuecomment-478794155) point out that this is limiting though, so there's still a possibility.

Ultimately, I think the answer is that `RefCell` does not work because the full-fledged feature hasn't been designed thoroughly enough yet. The Rust team likely implemented the basic feature so that we could have `Pin` as a `self` type and thus make futures work, and added a few other "easy" types to get more bang for their buck, but a proper and generic implementation has been deferred.